# How to match a tag not containing another one?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

I want to style a ul/li differently when it does not contain another tag ul/li.

UPDATED as I understand my question was misleading, I added the full scope explicitly (sorry about that).

The fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/v7nxB/

The html is as follows:

```html
Two-level nesting:

<ul>
    <li>Grain&nbsp;:
        <ul>
            <li>Baisse du rendement</li>
            <li>Sénescence plus rapide la plante</li>
            <li>Sensibilisation accrue à la fusariose des tiges</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Baisse du rendement</li>
    <li>Sénescence plus rapide la plante</li>
</ul>

One level:
<ul>
    <li>Baisse du rendement</li>
    <li>Sénescence plus rapide la plante</li>
    <li>Sensibilisation accrue à la fusariose des tiges</li>
</ul>
```

The current CSS (lessCSS code actually) is as follows:

```
ul { 
    &>li {
        &:after {
            content: " ;";
        }
        &:last-child:after {
            content: ".";
        }

        &>ul { 
            li:after {
                content: " (end)";
            }
            li:last-child:after {
                content: " (final end)";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result it produces is as follows:

```
Two-level nesting:

   o Grain
    — Baisse du rendement (end)
    — Sénescence plus rapide la plante (end)
    — Sensibilisation accrue à la fusariose des tiges (final end)
    ;
   o Baisse du rendement ;
   o Sénescence plus rapide la plante.

One level:
   o Baisse du rendement ;
   o Sénescence plus rapide la plante ;
   o Sensibilisation accrue à la fusariose des tiges.
```

One level is ok, but the two-level is not what I want.

Two-level should be as follows while one-level stays still:

```
   o Grain
    — Baisse du rendement ;
    — Sénescence plus rapide la plante ;
    — Sensibilisation accrue à la fusariose des tiges.
    (final end)
   o Baisse du rendement ;
   o Sénescence plus rapide la plante.
```

As you may understand, I'll replace (final end) by empty string once the CSS works.

Any idea?

UPDATE 2: I just found an interim work around with the help of a class (not great, but it works) (the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/v7nxB/1/))

Comment: `&:last-child:after { content: ". (final end)";}`?

Comment: Will there be arbitrary levels of nesting? If not, you should be able to just [swap the top-level `content` styles with the nested ones](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Qup9s/2).

Comment: @BoltClock: In my very case, I won't go into more additional level. So the two-level ul is what I need to solve.

Comment: OK, I've posted it as an answer.

Comment: I saw my question was not that good, I have updated it (including the fiddle).

Comment: Could you post a new fiddle?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated it.

Comment: I don't think there's any other workaround besides the one you have (adding a class).

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this,

#### Check this <kbd>[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qup9s/3/)</kbd>

#### Result

```
o Grain
    — Baisse du rendement ;
    — Sénescence plus rapide la plante ;
    — Sensibilisation accrue à la fusariose des tiges.
    (final end)
```

#### CSS

```
ul { 
    &>li {
        &:after {
            content: " ;";
        }
        &:last-child:after {
            content: "(final end)";
        }

        &>ul { 
            li:last-child:after {
                content: " .";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### `100% Worked`

Comment: Nope. Compare your result with the question.

Comment: @BoltClock i update my answer check now this is worked.

Comment: Now I'm on the fence - the `content: " (end)"` part seems to be missing completely. It might be important; I wouldn't recommend throwing away arbitrary values unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interim work around I've found which takes advantage of a separate class as follows:

```
Two-level nesting:

<ul>
    <li class="compact">Grain&nbsp;:
        <ul>
            <li>Baisse du rendement</li>
            <li>Sénescence plus rapide la plante</li>
            <li>Sensibilisation accrue à la fusariose des tiges</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Baisse du rendement</li>
    <li>Sénescence plus rapide la plante</li>
</ul>
```

The class I named "compact" is there to tell not to apply the rules that handle ul/li suffix.

The CSS becomes as follows:

```
ul { 
    &>li {
        &:after {
            content: " ;";
        }
        &:last-child:after {
            content: ".";
        }

        &.compact:after {
            content: "";
        }
    }
}
```

The inconvenient comes from the fact you need to add information to your data source which does not bear true semantic. But it works for now.

Hope someone might found a better way to proceed